# Evaluation order of `If` and `Sum`

Tags: summation, conditional

Where in the manual are the specifications for the order of evaluation that produce the following result?

```
Sum[If[OddQ[n], 1, 0]/n!, {n, 0, ∞}]
(*0*)
```

---

****Addendum****

Arguments about `If` being somewhat 'special' do not explain

```
Sum[If[OddQ[n], 1, 0]/n!, {n, 0, 10}]
(*result is not zero*)
```

---

*Original question*

Can you confirm the following is a bug?

```
Sum[If[OddQ[n], 1, 0]/n!, {n, 0, ∞}]
(*0*)
```

Adding up positive numbers should not result in zero! The answer should be

```
1/2 (E - 1/E)
```

I have MMA "11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"

Is `Sum` reliable?

Comment: The problem is that the `If` statement does not do what you think it does. It is evaluated immediately for general `n`, giving `If[OddQ[n], 1, 0]` --> 0, and thus your sum is really `Sum[0/n!, {n, 0, ∞}]`.

Comment: You could use Mod also `Sum[Mod[n, 2]/n!, {n, 0, Infinity}]` gives `-((1 - E^2)/(2 E))`

Comment: Like @Roman says. Additionally, it's usually a good habit to feed any software with input in a form that makes it less likely to run into unexpected issues like this one. In this case, `Sum[1/n!, {n, 1, \[Infinity], 2}]` is equivalent to your sum, and gives `Sinh[1]`, which in turn is equal to `1/2 (E - 1/E)`.

Comment: @corey979: Your statement reminds me of a joke by an architect: your toilet doesn't flush unless you hold the bathroom door open with your left leg because it is modern.

Comment: When in doubt, the `Trace` command shows you how an expression is evaluated.

Answer (score 8):

Not a bug. `If[OddQ[n], 1, 0]` evaluates to `0` because a symbol isn't an odd integer.

`If` is a programming construct, while `Sum` is attempting symbolic analysis. `Sum` can only analyze mathematical expressions, not programs. And in this case, `Sum` never sees your program, as it has already evaluated to `0` when `Sum` starts processing it.

Responding to a comment:

In `Sum[c[n] = 1/n!, {n, 0, ∞}]`, no "assignment" takes place. When c[n] = 1/n! is evaluated, it defines a "downvalue" for `c`, and yields `1/n!`. The resulting expression is `Sum[1/n!, {n, 0, ∞}]`, which is perfectly suited to symbolic analysis. The downvalue doesn't get used, although if later in the session you try to use `c[n]`, it will be replaced by `1/n!`, assuming you use it literally (`c[m]` or `c[1]` won't match).

You will find it very frustrating to apply concepts from procedural programming like "assignment" to *Mathematica* without an appreciation that *Mathematica* isn't fundamentally procedural in design: it is an expression rewriting language.

Comment: The help page for `If` does have the phrase "procedural programming structure"; however, it is unclear to me that procedural programming structures are (or are not) expressions. Moreover, `Attributes[If]` and `Attributes[Sum]` do not reflect any special status beyond `HoldRest` and `HoldAll`.

Comment: Moreover, the manual says "The Wolfram Language supports all standard procedural programming constructs, but often extends them through integration into its more general symbolic programming environment." I do not see any hints that the integration is partial.

Comment: @Hector Procedural programming constructs don't have special attributes to distinguish them from symbolic constructs.

Comment: That is exactly my point. How do I know what is supposed to work. For example, Sum[c[n] = 1/n!, {n, 0, ∞}] is the sum of assignments. Assignments are listed within the "Procedural Programming" help page. So, it is it not true that all procedural programming constructs fail with `Sum`.

Comment: @Hector Generally, if the result of an evaluation depends on evaluation order, then do not use the involved constructs for symbolic math. It's clear that the constructs describe a program, not a mathematical statement. (What I mean by evaluation order: Here it matters whether we substitute a number for `n` first, then evaluate, or evaluate first, then substitute.) If a function has a name ending in `Q`, you can assume that it is not suitable for symbolic math. Notice how `Positive` does *not* have the `Q` and how `Positive[n]` does not evaluate at all.

Answer (score 8):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Sum[If[OddQ[n], 1, 0]/n!, {n, 0, ∞}]

(* 0 *)
```

The problem is with using [`OddQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OddQ.html). From the documentation, "OddQ[expr] returns False unless expr is manifestly an odd integer (i.e. has head Integer, and is odd)."

```
OddQ[n]

(* False *)
```

Then

```
If[OddQ[n], 1, 0]

(* 0 *)
```

Given a better behaved argument, [`If`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/If.html) will work. From the documentation, "If[condition, t, f] is left unevaluated if condition evaluates to neither True nor False. "

```
If[Mod[n, 2] == 1, 1, 0]

(* If[Mod[n, 2] == 1, 1, 0] *)
```

Then

```
Sum[If[Mod[n, 2] == 1, 1, 0]/n!, {n, 0, ∞}]

(* Sqrt[π/2] BesselI[1/2, 1] *)
```

Alternatively,

```
% // FullSimplify

(* Sinh[1] *)
```

Or the form that you expected

```
% // TrigToExp // Simplify

(* (-1 + E^2)/(2 E) *)
```

Nonetheless, using `If` as a numeric function is not recommended.

Answer (score 5):

[`Trace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html) shows clearly what is going on:

```
Trace @ Sum[If[OddQ[n], 1, 0]/n!, {n, 0, ∞}]

(*    {Sum[If[OddQ[n], 1, 0]/n!, {n, 0, ∞}], 
       {{{OddQ[n], False}, If[False, 1, 0], 0}, 0/n!, 0},
       Sum[0, {n, 0, ∞}],
       0}                                                    *)
```

So first `OddQ[n]` evaluates to `False` (because, as @johndoty states, the symbol `n` is not odd in general), and then `If[False, 1, 0]` evaluates to `0`.